# Enable "Extend to children" doesn't work - Keycloak UI

Tags: keycloak

I use the 24.0.1 version of Keycloak and I'm facing with the following problem:

- I created a parent group "admin" and added some users
- I created a child group for "admin" named "admin1" and added some users here too

When I want to create a GROUP based policy, and I add my parent group to it, I cannot check the "Extend to children":

[image]

I tried it with multiple parent and child groups and I tried with some other versions of Keycloak, but it still didn't work.

I need to mention that I'm just exploring the Keycloak, so I think it could be a configuration problem that I don't know how to set properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use <kbd>Add groups</kbd>Instead of `Extend to children`

[image]

Result

[image]

`admin` Group members
[image]

`admin/admin1` Group members

[image]

Comment: Meanwhile I found another approach for my idea. But anyway, thanks for the reply!

Comment: OK, good to hear you got it. if my answer help you can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I myself experience this weird behavior and, in fact, users from sub groups are well affected by this policy (you can edit the user knowing his id...) and I found that this is in fact an issue affecting listing users and groups. Cf : https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/16966

BTW I don't know when this checkbox is active / used.

While waiting for this to be fixed, the only way I know is what Bench Vue mention, explicitly add subgroups to your policy...

"fun" fact, this option is indeed not read only on the API side (you can enable the checkbox with your browser console and it is well saved), but I didn't see any changes in behavior.